# Create something of similar to Watson Virtual Agents

Tags: ibm-watson, watson-conversation

I've seen the gif on this page: 
https://github.com/watson-virtual-agents/chat-widget

And I want to creato with IBM Watson Conversation tool something similat to this

[image]

In which user can choose between some options inserted in a cicular bottom. Do you know how is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty sure you can do this example.

The summary you need to know: Watson Conversation is one endpoint REST API, so, you can call this service in your backend and to anything in your front end, for shows the messages for your user in different forms (front-end).

In this case, your example is one Web page, so, probably inside the Watson conversation, you need to add the `html` for the `buttons` in the response.

You can see [this example](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/conversation-simple/issues/65) from one IBM Developer - Ashley using buttons in Watson.

[Conversation simple](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/conversation-simple/) is one awesome example that you can use to understand how Watson Conversation works and one based for your projects using this API. This project is built in [Node.js](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v5.x/api/).

- See the Official [API Reference](https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/conversation/api/v1/) for use IBM Watson Conversation.

Comment: see my answer below

Answer (score -2):

Ok.

I've inserted this code

```
<script>
    function yesBye() {
        var latestResponse = Api.getResponsePayload();
        var context = latestResponse.context;
        Api.sendRequest("yes", context);
    }
    function noBye() {
        var latestResponse = Api.getResponsePayload();
        var context = latestResponse.context;
        Api.sendRequest("no", context);
    }
</script>
```

inside /ui/index.html (he suggests me to sobstitute " with ' and I make it)

this code

```
#button-yes {
    width: 100px;
    margin: 5px;
    font-size: 16px;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 2px;
    background-color:#66B266;
    color: white;
}

#button-no {
    width: 100px;
    margin: 5px;
    font-size: 16px;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 2px;
    background-color:#ff3232;
    color: white;
}
```

inside /ui/css/conversation.css and inside /ui/css/main.css

and this code

```
"text": "Would you link to end our conversation?\n\n<button id=\"button-yes\" onclick=\"yesBye();\">Yes</button> <button id=\"button-no\" onclick=\"noBye();\">No</button>"
```

inside the code js editor of the single node

This is the situation

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jWrLf.png)

it means that page recognise button but don't recognise their css style.
The structure of my project is the same of this (https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/car-dashboard) and after every edit I deploy again the project. Where is the mistake?

Comment: I really recommend to you study about css, html and javascript, and the client/server architecture. But, in your case, you need to add the `#button-no` and `#button-yes` css style in your [index.html](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/car-dashboard/blob/master/ui/index.html) with one `<style>paste the css</style>` tag. The style does not work because you need to insert inside the appropriate tag.

Comment: see my answer below

Answer (score -2):

Ok, but it's not a CSS problem. By losing the buttons, any type of modification I make to the index.html file does not appear.
Not even if I try to replace the "Type something" string in the bottom box.
I tried to empty the cache, resume the deploy at every modification, check that the service names and contents of the manifest.yml file were correct, but nothing. Work space and environment variables are correct.
Every time I hit the play button in the eclipse ID I see this

https://i.stack.imgur.com/dhkBe.jpg

with the "Failed to read application content" error message.
Is there anything inside the code (which you can find here https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/car-dashboard) that blocks any type of modification?

Comment: Try to add the css in the main.css [here](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/car-dashboard/blob/master/ui/css/main.css).

Comment: It doen't function. It's not a problem of CSS because if I try to edit the same string text, it doesn't change. Every time that I try to clock on play button to distribute i've seen the "Failed to read application content" error message.